# Flutter: Scroll View Issue with ListView

Tags: forms, flutter, listview, dart, scrollview

I have a page describing MessageDetails. What I expect is that when it scroll up, it is not only scroll up the form part(ie Expanded widget) , but also other widget, like Text, Row, WebView, etc. How can I fix this, or shouldn't I use ListView to build the form?

Below is the code:

```
child: Scaffold(
 appBar: AppBar(),
 body: Column(
  children: <Widget> [
   Text(message.title),
   Row(// other message detail),
   Divider(),
   Container(
    child: WebView()
   ),
   Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: message.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Column(
       children: [
        Text(message.questionTitle),
        Form(
         key: _formKey,
         child: TextFormField(),
        )
       ]
      )
    )],),)
```

Comment: try wrapping the column in a SingleChildScrollView widget

Comment: I fixed it by using SingleChildScrollView and have the primary set to false and shrinkWrap set to true in ListView. Many thanks!